# Enforcing case-sensitive string match when requiring node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I noticed that some of my pushes to heroku fail because there's a mismatch in capitalization in a dependency in my package.json with what I actually require in javascript. For example, in package.json, I may have something named "somepackage", but in my javascript file I have `require("somePackage")`.  Locally, this works fine, but on heroku it fails.  Is there a node setting to enforce case sensitivity so it can fail locally for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this discussion on github https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3914

The preferred naming convention for npm packages is "all-lowercase". you should probably make the necessary changes in your code to follow this convention.

mixing cases brings cross-platform problems mostly because linux has a case-sensitive file system while windows and macOS by default have a case-insensitive file system.

The "all-lowercase" convention was made to avoid surprises such as the ones you describe.

If your are working on Mac OS X, you can check how your file system is configured by following the first answer on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-bash-in-osx-case-insensitive

Comment: Exactly; you see it on Heroku but not locally because OSX / Windows don't see the difference but Heroku runs on Ubuntu (linux), which does.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an NPM module that does this and also checks to ensure that all the dependencies referenced in your code are reflected in your package.json file:

nodejs-dep-check

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-dep-check

the purpose of course is to save you time so that you don't initialize a build or experience a runtime error without a test/check beforehand.

Comment: this is being updated today, it's relatively new but it's better than the other modules that attempt this